# Python 2.7.8 IDLE will not open on Mavericks

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-mavericks, python-idle

I installed Python 2.7.8 for a class about a week ago and I used it all week and it opened and worked.  I even installed the updated ActiveTcl 8.5.15 when I heard about the IDLE crash issue. After installing ActiveTcl 8.5.15 it continued to work perfectly, but now whenever I try to open IDLE it opens for a second then crashes. After I try to open it and it crashes, the next time I try it just bounces on my dock and nothing happens. I've tried reinstalling and everything, but nothing has worked. As of now, I haven't found anyone else that has ever run into this problem.

Comment: What happens if you try to start IDLE from a Terminal (command line)? Are there any useful error messages that may indicate the source of the problem?

Comment: Nope, I just tried it again now. No error messages at all.

Comment: Turns out I actually get this error message
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "shift"

Answer (score 0):

Your afterthought comment has the answer: somehow, 'Shift' got re-written as 'shift' in one of two files.  The fix is to change it back.  I reproduced the error `_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "shift"` on Windows by editing each file. I will let you translate the file paths to osx paths.

`.../python27/lib/idlelib/config-keys.def` This file should not be touched after installation.

`/users/Terry/.idlerc/config-keys.cfg`  This file is written if you edit Options / Idle preferences / Keys / Custom Key Bindings.  It can also be edited by hand.  It is read on startup if Use custom is checked.

One can delete any or all of the files in .idlerc and Idle will run.

I added a note about this specific report to a Python [tracker issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue11437).  You are not, unfortunately, the first with a similar problem.  Fixing this and similar problems is high on my priority list.  I am very curious, however, which file is bad and how this happened.  Did you edit key bindings either through the dialog or an editor?  Or do you think something else corrupted the file?